# get the height of a another web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code:

```
  $("#galleries").load("letters/index.php");
  $(function(){
  $('#galleries').hide().fadeIn(1500);
  });
```

everything works fine. My problem is, I got about 8 scripts like that, and whenever I switch the content of the div, it doesn't do that smoothly, first of all, it clears the DIV and let me see that for about 0.7 seconds, after that, it loads ALL of the content within a second, and it's really disturbing my eye.

I thought about a solution, that I will get the height of the page I wanna load, and then set the DIV height to that height, and then load the info. Will it work? because, the LOAD function removes everything from the div, will it remove the height property as well?

generally, this is what im trying to achieve:

```
 //GET TARGET'S HEIGHT
 //SET #galleries TO THAT HEIGHT
 $("#galleries").load("letters/index.php");
  $(function(){
 $('#galleries').hide().fadeIn(1500);
 });
```

I don't know how to get the target's height and set it. But anyways, will it work? or maybe someone has another solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a CSS fix (i know this is not what you want), but to avoid the up and dow of the content load, you can have a min-height of some value.

As far as i know, to get the hight of a page it needs be rendered

Comment: but, everypage im loading has a different height. It won't solve my problem, especially when some pages are about 400px height, and some are 2000px height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the complete callback of `load()` which allows you to run code **after** content is loaded.

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
/* hide first, then load*/
 $('#galleries').hide().load("letters/index.php", function(){
      /* new content now exists*/
      $(this).slideDown()/* or fadeIn() or any other effect*/
  });
});
```

`SlideDown` is not dependent on overall height so will smoothly move content below it down

Comment: Thanks! you code works perfectly!

But there is only 1 problem, it starts sliding down the div, it slides it for about 50px, and then, it drops down in a second and it just show all of the content >.< how do i make the slidedown event to load the whole div with the slide down?

Comment: make sure all your html is valid, and make sure page has valid doctype and isn't running in quirks mode. Also.. is this a table?

Comment: nope, let me show you the HTML:

http://pastebin.com/PZKMTTcX

css:

http://pastebin.com/mzDgTarn

any issue?

Comment: create a demo with css and html in jsfiddle.net. Hard to scan html and css in different files to look for potential issues when can see them in seconds in a browser console. Just load a ton of `Ipsum Lorem` into the DIV

Comment: well, not sure if the demo is going to work since the page loads a PHP file and I have NO idea how to do include this... If you have an email, you can freely use TeamViewer and see the whole code.
I'm facing problems with creating the jsfiddle file :s this is what I got : http://jsfiddle.net/7UTA7/

Comment: forget the ajax..just paste some static content in so can visualize the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7UTA7/
not sure if it works >.< It's really hard for me to use this site >.< Please consider the TeamViewer option? I don't mind posting the answer after we solve it.
wow! I just noticed that it didn't save my changes!

Comment: seems to work fine with 30 paragraphs... I set duration to 1500: http://jsfiddle.net/7UTA7/11/show/

Comment: one other option to make speed of slide more dependent on height would be to insert content into another offscreen DIV with same width..then get it's height and set the slide duration based on height

Comment: so why it's not working >.<?
I think I have an idea why, im using LOAD function to load the contents, so maybe the page doesnt know the height of the content? 
I'm really lost >.< I tried to get the height after loading and then set the height and then do the slidedown, I couldn't write a proper code to that. Any idea?

Comment: works with css you gave me. Could be some invalid html being loaded or something else in live page causing problems. Can't get height of a hidden element..it is zero. Run the other html through w3c validator

Comment: what do you mean by "run the other html through w3c validator"?
you said something about set the info to another div and extract the height and set it to the display div, how do I do that?

Comment: "The file canno't be checked" :O

Comment: it says that the page is okay, and there are no warnings. Any idea for a solution ?

Comment: i did remove `overflow:hidden` from css for galleries

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't slove the problem. I think the problem has something to do with the height of the div, because it does the slideDown for about 50px and then it stops and just shows all of the content.